# Как добавить это в проект Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Next we need parser class to parse api response JSON. So create a new class in your library package name it as JSONParser.java and fill it with following code. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ из этого примера

Comment: Так а в чём проблема-то? Берёте код, создаёте файл, пихаете внутрь код, сохраняете.

Comment: В этом и небольшая проблема, как создать этот самый файл? На сайте написано создать класс, только не знаю как

Comment: @Adaus, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно вот этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27545431/3212712), выдающейся гуглом на запрос

> create class android studio

надо в проекте в папке **src** создать папку **main** а в ней, с помощью правой кнопки

> new->folder->Java Folder

после этого в появившейся папке **java** можно правой кнопкой создавать **Java Class** файлы.